# Unsure of how to preform a count within a select

Tags: mysql

I've tried a number of ways of approaching this and so far all have failed.

I have 3 tables. A user table containing all account information. An events table with all details of future promotions and a list table that holds a list table that has all the people invited to the event and their status on going.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT u.Name, l.*, e.*
FROM event e, user u, list l
WHERE e.event_id IN (SELECT l.event_id 
                     FROM list l, event e, user u
                     WHERE e.event_id=l.event_id 
                     AND l.user_id=1)
AND u.user_id=e.creator_id
AND l.event_id IN (SELECT l.event_id 
                   FROM list l 
                   WHERE l.user_id=1 
                   AND l.event_id=e.event_id)
AND l.user_id=1 ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
```

I'm trying to add a simple count into it so that a new column of "Going" is returned, this'll count all the people who are invited:

```
 | User_ID | Name | Event_ID | Event_Name | Date | List_ID | Accepted | Going |
 |---------|------|----------|------------|------|---------|----------|-------|
```

Adding a simple count to my query brings back an error of "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now":

```
SELECT u.Name, l.*, e.*, (SELECT l.user_id, COUNT(*) as count
                          FROM list l
                          GROUP BY l.user_id
                          ORDER BY count DESC) as Going)
FROM event e, user u, list l 
WHERE e.event_id IN (SELECT l.event_id 
                     FROM list l, event e, user u
                     WHERE e.event_id=l.event_id 
                     AND l.user_id=1)
AND u.user_id=e.creator_id
AND l.event_id IN (SELECT l.event_id 
                   FROM list l 
                   WHERE l.user_id=1 
                   AND l.event_id=e.event_id)
AND l.user_id=1 ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
```

I've read into it and it seems to be an issue with the order of calling functions. I'm unsure how to structure it as the count seems to be in the correct place.

Comment: I have not seen this problem, but the first thing I would do is break this up so that I am putting together temporary tables and get the query to work with those. Then, if you want, you can re-coalesce the statements.

Answer (score 0):

You want a correlated subquery, not a `group by`:

```
SELECT u.Name, l.*, e.*, (SELECT l.user_id, COUNT(*) as count
                          FROM list l2
                          WHERE l2.user_id = l.user_id
                         ) as Going
```

I'm not sure what the `count(*)` was doing in the subquery.  Also, you should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax, rather than implicit joins which are less powerful, more prone to error, and harder to read.